# Calling a function to change state in parent component from the child component in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using props to change the state of my parent component.

The state of the parent component is:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    open: false
  }
}
```

Parent Component render:

```
//the state of the button is currently false but when a user presses it the state is set to true
<button whichState={this.handleChange} onClick={this.setStateToTrue}>
```

Then when the user does some action in the child component to trigger a call to a function in the parent component. I do this through props:

Child Component:

```
//User does some action that calls a function that calls whichState
callWhichState: function() {
  this.props.whichState();
}
```

Back into my parent component the handleChange function simply sets the state of open:

```
handleChange: function() {
  this.setState({      
    open: false
  });
}
```

Right now handleChange is being called as I can console log the state from within it. However, the state never switches to false. Does anyone know what mistakes I made here?

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: Try passing the `this.setState` as a prop down to your child.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to toggle the `open` state of your parent component when the button is clicked?

```jsx
var Parent = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            open: false
        }
   }
   handleChange: function(){
        this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
   }
   render: function(){
        return (
            <Child changeHandler={this.handleChange}></Child>
        )
   }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    handleChange: function(){
        this.props.changeHandler();
    }
    render: function(){
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleChange}></button>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not at my computer at the moment, but I will try this as soon as I get back. However in this case I need to be calling changeHandler in the Child element right? so rather than `this.props.handleChange()` it should be `this.props.changeHandler`

Comment: just tested it and the state still never changes in the parent component

Comment: @ogk oops thanks for catching my mistake. Yes, you should be called `this.props.changeHandler`